# Deutsche Aussprache & Betonung von »Ukraine«

Tags: pronunciation

*Regarding English pronunciation, I’d add an English translation, but it wouldn’t make sense. In English, `you-craine` seems to be the correct pronunciation, while it ought to be vocalized as `you-cray-een`.*

---

Ich habe zur [Ukraine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine) immer schon `ukra-ihne` gesagt. Als störend habe ich die `u-kraine`-Aussprechenden empfunden. Bestätigt wurde ich dann bei `Україна`, da es ein kyrillisches [`і`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86) mit einem [Trema](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema) enthält. Obwohl Tremata im Deutschen leider fehlen, ist ihr diakritischer Hinweis klar.

Ein des Deutschen mächtiger Ukrainer – ein mutmaßlicher `u-kra-ihner`, anstelle eines [`u-krainers`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krainer_Wurst) – kam nun leider mit der (vermeintlich) falschen Aussprache `u-kraine` um die Ecke. Wikipedia behauptet indes, die Aussprache sei `[ʔukʁaˈʔiːnə]`, aber auch `[ʔuˈkʁaɪ̯nə]`.

**Gibt es eine eindeutige standardsprachliche Betonung im Deutschen? Wenn ja, wieso?**

**Sind beide gleichwertig? Wieso ist eine der möglichen Aussprachen bevorzugt?**

Comment: Was macht den Ukrainer zum Gewährsmann für deutsche Aussprache, außer dass er des deutschen mächtig sein soll? Ein Spanier wird vielleicht auch eher Barfellonna als Barzelohna sagen - die spanische Aussprache ist aber für die deutsche belanglos und gehörte in einem entsprechenden Dings diskutiert.

Comment: @userunknown: Es reicht, dass er ein Ukrainer aus Kiew ist. Im Zweifelsfall spricht er „Ukraine“ seiner Heimatsprache entsprechend aus – also so, wie man es in Herkunftsland ausspricht. Es ist nur ein Indiz auf der Suche nach der richtigen deutschen Aussprache.

Comment: @Jan: That just means it’s a matter of conflicting pronunciation in English as well.

Comment: Actually, after checking Wiktionary again and then checking a random Youtube video about the Ukraine from BBC news, I take back my earlier comment and conclude that that lady taught us crap. (I’m not even surprised.)

Answer (score 5):

Diese Frage hat mich auch schon beschäftigt. Bevor ich aber zu meiner »damals« gefundenen Antwort übergehe, werfen wir einen kurzen Blick auf [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ukraine): Dort werden direkt hintereinander die beiden Aussprachen *U-kra-i-ne* und *U-krai-ne* genannt, und die entsprechenden Wortreime als *-ine* und *-eine* gegeben. Beim [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ukraine) gehen sie sogar einen Schritt weiter, und bieten für beide Varianten Hörbeispiele an.

»Damals« ist vor einigen Monaten gewesen, als ich einen russischsprachigen ukrainischen Kollegen noch als Laborpartner hatte. Ich habe ihn gefragt, wie man es denn auf Russisch und auf Ukrainisch ausspräche, das Land. Beide Varianten sind aufgetaucht, wobei er mir das, was wie *U-kra-i-ne* geklungen hat, als ukrainische Aussprache, und das, was wie *U-krai-ne* geklungen hat, als russische Aussprache verkauft hat.

Übrigens bietet Wiktionary auch Ausspracheaufnahmen, zu finden ist die ukrainische Version unter der ukrainischen Schreibweise [Україна](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0) und die russische Version unter der russischen Schreibweise [Украина](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). Ich muss sagen, dass diese beiden Aussprachen für mich beide eher wie *U-kra-i-ne* klingen – aber selbstverständlich ist die Aussprache in der Landessprache kein Anhaltspunkt dafür, wie etwas auf Deutsch ausgesprochen wird, vergleiche [*Ecuador*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ecuador#Ecuador_.28Spanisch.29) (ebenfalls mit Hörbeispiel).

Comment: Natürlich gibt es in den ganzen russischen Ländern unterschiedliche Sprachvarietäten, von denen man sich eine kanonische Version heraussuchen muss. Russen sind da mglw. nicht sooo genau. Und wenn ich sonst Wikimedia gerne verteidige, hätte ich in diesem Fall gerne ein andere, weitere Primärquelle.

Comment: @dakab Duden tuts?

Comment: Ich vertraue deinem Laborpartner nicht ganz. "Ukraine" auf Russisch ist /ukrɑˈjinɑ/ — und zwar sehr einstimmig, wie man auf [Forvo](http://forvo.com/word/украина/) hören kann. Und wenn er Ukrainer ist, spricht er wohl eher ukrainischen Dialekt, und sein Russisch sollte "Standard-Russisch" entsprechen.

Comment: @Em1 Dein Missvertrauen in allen Ehren, aber Russisch ist seine Muttersprache. D.h. er spricht bestimmt irgendeinen »fiesen Dialekt«. Andererseits schreibe ich weiter unten, dass sich die russische Aussprache auf Wiktionary für mich auch eher wie *U-kra-i-ne* anhört.